# Optimize multiple Composer VCS repository paths

Tags: composer-php

I've got some composer.json files that contain sections like this:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "http://svn.example.com/libs/",
        "package-path": "Package1"
    },
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "http://svn.example.com/libs/",
        "package-path": "Package2"
    },
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "http://svn.example.com/libs/",
        "package-path": "Package3"
    }
],

"require": {
    "ident/Package1": "~2.0",
    "ident/Package2": "~3.0",
    "ident/Package3": "~1.0"
}
```

That is, the individual packages are in subdirectories beneath the ../trunk directory in Subversion, instead of their own project directories with the standard ./[trunk,tags,branches] arrangement.

Is there a way to optimize this composer.json so as not to have to repeat the VCS `type` and `url` values when only the `package-path` changes?  Assume that I cannot change the Subversion directory layout, but just about anything else would be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot think of a way to optimize this.

The real potential for optimization is on a completely different level: The way you are adding private repositories requires you to always add every one of them to the root `composer.json` file even if the packages are not directly included there.

This is a lot of maintenance work. It would be better if you can for example use [Satis](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md) to create a local package repository and only add this single info everywhere. Using Satis, you will then only add your private repositories once - and then it doesn't really matter whether or not you repeat a URL. Adding new packages will only be done once in the Satis configuration, and then be available everywhere.

Comment: I was afraid that this would be the case.  I think I will lobby to have our Subversion repository arranged in a more standard fashion.  Otherwise, I'll see if I can implement a Satis solution.  Thanks!

Comment: Optimizing your SVN will not really help you - you would gain the benefit of only writing two lines instead of three for each package. Go for the Satis option, it will help you become independent of the type and style of package hosting. It will also allow you to have local copies of the packages you are using from Github or elsewhere. (just in case you'd consider Github downtimes during your deployment inconvenient).

Comment: Thank you for the additional advice.  Indeed, I have both a large library of my own packages, and a bunch I'm using from Github/Packagist.  So Satis seems like the preferred choice.

Comment: There is a way, if you could get zip url of the repository, you could use that as a dist instead of VCS. reference: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#using-private-repositories
basically downloading zip files first before installing them for efficiency